# How do I create a link to a MSE post? Please provide detail.

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

Please explain the following explanation about [Links from the MathJax guide](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links)  (quoted below).  It talks about writing links but not about creating them.

1. How does the following change if I want to reference a posted Math Stack Exchange question or page?
2. Do I need to type the whole URL or can I copy it from someplace? Where on the MSE page can I copy it from?
3. Can I keep multiple MSE pages open to go back and forth for copying?
4. What is meant by the first line of the second paragraph? What text is being referred to? Where is the URL?

> There are three ways to write links. Each is easier to read than the last:
>       Here's an inline link to [Google](http://www.google.com/).
>       Here's a reference-style link to [Google][1].
>       Here's a very readable link to [Yahoo!][yahoo].
>
> ```
>   [1]: http://www.google.com/  
>   [yahoo]: http://www.yahoo.com/
> ```
>
> You can also select text and press CTRL+L to make it a link, or press CTRL+L with no text selected to insert a link at the current position.
>      The link definitions can appear anywhere in the document -- before or after the place where you use them. The link definition names [1] and [yahoo] can be any unique string, and are case-insensitive; [yahoo] is the same as [YAHOO].

Comment: It seems to me there's nothing stopping you from keeping as many m.se pages open as you like, within the limitations your hardware and software and your ISP impose, but it should be easy enough for you to experiment to see whether this is correct.

Comment: Regarding question 2: Look at the bottom left of the post you want to link. For example, refer to your question above. Right below the **support** tag, you should see four grey links: share, edit, close, flag. Click "share". This will give you a link that is already highlighted and ready to be copied.

Comment: Note that the ways of creating links *from* (in) a StackExchange post are features of Markdown syntax (nothing to do with MathJax).   Possibly you are asking about creating links *from* one StackExchange post *to* another StackExchange post. You haven't expressed very clearly what you wanted to do.  For example, some members place links to SE posts on Facebook, Google+, etc. elsewhere on the Web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. How does the following change if I want to reference a posted Math Stack Exchange question or page?

If you want to reference a Math Stack Exchange question in a post it suffices to paste the URL into the post. What will be displayed is the title of the question. This work for posts (questions and answers) yet not for comments.

You can also use any other method mentioned, but the above is simplest.

Other URLs are also turned into links, and this is sometimes good enough if the URL is short and simple. For long and complicated ones, with special characters etc, it might break and also it looks not so good.

> 2. Do I need to type the whole URL or can I copy it from someplace? Where on the MSE page can I copy it from?

You can retrieve a short URL for the post via clicking "share" below the post.  The format is `https://math.stackexchange.com/q/{questionID}/{userID}`.  *Note:* this link is personalized via the userID. If you want an anonymous link just leave the second number away.

You can also just copy the URL from your browser's address bar while on the page of the question. Note though that if you came to the question's page following the link to an answer, the link will also be focused on the answer. To be sure you get a link to the question post you can click the title of the  question to refocus.

> 3. Can I keep multiple MSE pages open to go back and forth for copying?

The site does not prevent multiple pages being open in different browser tab or browser windows. Some care is needed if you have the very same page open several times as there could be interferences especially if you alter one version.

The page even automatically saves drafts of posts. Thus you could even navigate away from the page in which you momentarily compose a post and then come back to it with what you wrote still in place.

This should work fine for the described use-case, where you just briefly leave your post and do not do much anything active on the page before coming back, but do note that only one draft is saved per type of post (question and answer, yet not comments) and this not permanently.

> 4. What is meant by the first line of the second paragraph? What text is being referred to? Where is the URL?

If you hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key pressed and press <kbd>L</kbd> in addition you will get a pop-up window where you can insert the URL for a link (either type it in  or copy it in). This will result in `[enter link description here][1]` being inserted plus a  `[1]: {your url}`
at the end. You can then edit the "enter link description here" to have a more meaningful link.

If you first high-light some text such as this example text and do the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>L</kbd> while the text is highlighted  then what you get is  `[such as this example text][1]` instead, so that you do not have to give a link description.

Instead of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>L</kbd> you can also click the link-symbol in the tool bar of the editor.

Note that this works for posts (yet not comments).

For links in comments you can use the inline style or just paste the URL. (Note that in this case URLs' of SE posts are not converted to a nicer format.)

Comment: I think that mentioning of drafts without the caveat that you only get one draft for answer and one draft per question (and no drafts for comments) is borderline irresponsible. :)

Comment: Also, it might be worth mentioning, for [Dedekind-]completeness, that in the comments either bare URLs or inline linking, but none of that other stuff.

Comment: I'll edit it in a bit later.

Comment: @quid your answer is clear and helpful. Is there any other way I could have gotten this info as efficiently? Why is my question getting down votes? How do we preserve the Q &A for future newbies?

Comment: @StephenMeskin I think your question is fine. You read the standard documentation beforehand and still had questions, so you asked.  Downvotes on meta do not necessarily mean that the question is bad; voting is intended to be subjective on meta. Maybe some think that you could have experimented more before asking. But there are also advantages to asking.  Honestly I was also surprise about the score of the question.